# Antlr4 How can I create a parser rule that checks if class name and constructor is named the same?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to figure out how i can create a parser rule in Antlr4 where **two tokens need to be the same value.** What I am trying to achieve is to check if a class name and a constructor name is the same

Below is a pseudo rule of what i want to achieve where the two **"identifier"** is suppose to be equal.

```
compilation_unit :
                      'class' identifier
                      '{'
                            identifier '(' ARGUMENTS ')'
                            '{'

                            '}'
                      '};'
                  ;
```

Comment: usually you do this when you're evaluating the AST (after tokenizing and parsing), i.e. in a validation step (usually combined with a first transformation of the AST)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is **context-sensitive**, and you can't do [context-sensitiveness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_language) in a context-free grammar. You will need to use [actions](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/actions.md#Actions+and+Attributes) or a parser tree walking pattern (listener ou visitor) to do that. Here's an example using actions:

```
class:
     'class' cname=IDENTIFIER
     '{'
         'public' ctor=IDENTIFIER '(' args? ')'
         '{' '}'
     '}'
     
     { if (!$ctor.getText().equals($cname.getText())) {
          System.out.println("Not a constructor!");
       }
     }
 ;
```

<sub>Not actually tested, and I don't use actions that often, maybe I missed something</sub>

Comment: The link for `actions` is broken!

Comment: @msangel thanks for the pointer, it seems Antlr moved their documentation to Github.